# if statement should print string values

Tags: java

How do I print result from if statements in Java? This result should be assigned to some variable, that variable should print result in string. Currently, my code is like this. I want to store simple & extended into a single variable, so that i should able to call this variable anywhere in the program. There it should print "simple" or "extended".

```
if(loc[i]==1) {
    System.out.println("simple");
}
else if(loc[i]>1) {
    System.out.println("extended");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
String s = (loc[i]==1 ? "simple" : (loc[i]>1 ? "extended" : null));
```

Answer (score 4):

You mean like this:

```
String mode;

if(loc[i]==1)
    mode = "simple";
else if(loc[i]>1)
    mode = "extended";
else
    mode = "error";
System.out.println(mode);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String type;
if( loc[i] == 1 )
{
    type = "simple";
}
else if( loc[i] > 1)
{
    type = "extended";
}
else 
{
    type = null;
}

// variable 'type' can now be used in the same block of code
System.out.println( type );
```

If you want to use this variable anywhere in your program, you will have to either declare the variable at a higher scope to be accessible or return this variable from this code block.

Comment: giving me the following error variable type might not have been initialized

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you need following

```
private static final SIMPLE_STRING = "simple";
private static final EXTENDED_STRING = "extended";

if(loc[i]==1) {
    System.out.println(SIMPLE_STRING );
}
else if(loc[i]>1) {
    System.out.println(EXTENDED_STRING );
}
```